# How do I know that a user is on a form item in Vue / Buefy?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to trigger an event once the user focuses on a form element (made with `Vue / Buefy`). I'm new to this, maybe somebody can tell me how do I trigger it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use event handling in the input element like this

```
<input @focus="yourMethod" type="text>
// or
```

now when the user focus on the element **yourMethod** will be called

learn more
[Event Handling in Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html)